# Spring boot: How do I update large set of data?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, microservices, spring-rest

I have micro-service architecture (running on Kubernetes).

Let's say I have an entity called 'Product' with more than 1 million records in my service version 1.0.

Now I am trying to update server to version 2.0 and 2.0 introduces new entity named 'ProductAnalysis'.  For 2.0 to work properly, I need to iterate over all 1 million 'Product' records and calculate some numbers for once when version is updated.

What is the best way to do this?  I tried to create a hidden REST API which triggers looping over all 1 million records using JPA Pagination but the server runs out of memory when I do that.

I see some post suggest using 'Spring Batch' but I am not sure if I can use in my case.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide the code impls for this for loop and the request. Also are you using asynchronous transactions or synchronous. Out of memory happens when lot of records piles up and waiting to be processed.

Comment: Divide your data in several batches and take multi-threading/asynchronous approach to save the batches using JPA transaction. This approach works even more faster if you have data in several XML files. So if your DBMS has export to XML feature you can use that to export your data in batches.

Comment: Is it normal to create hidden REST endpoint to trigger this?

Comment: I would delegate this job to SQL directly I think.

Answer (score 1):

This may be not the perfect answer considering spring as a technology but I am trying to give answer in the context of Microservice.

1. For Such scenario few thing you have to decide and based on that you can select the approach.

   - Is this one time job or it needs to perform frequently ?
   - If this is one time job for migration 1.0 to 2.0 , you can create utility that perform this job. Here also if there is issue related to timeout due to large set of data update. Take following approach.

     - It may possible that not all product used at one so update those that is active or such status. Decide batch on that ( Like 100 items per batch)
     - If no such criteria then process as per your wish but choose small batch as well as time during which site is less active to end user.
2. Hidden REST API

   - This is completely fine approach provided it is protected and not consume by end user directly in any case for security reason.
   - Mostly those type of EndPoint refer as a "Private EndPoint" which available to within services but not externally available.